# Percent Increase of Data

Tags: recreational-mathematics, percentages, word-problem

Accidents in a certain town with about 20% more this year than last year. This year there were 840 accidents. How many accidents were there last year?
Would all I do be 840+840(.2)=1,008.  Can Somebody explain?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks; I'm still learning to read.

Comment: If there were **more** accidents this year than last year, and there were $840$ accidents this year, how can there possibly have been $1008$ last year?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the number of accidents last year. This year there were 20% more accidents than last year; in other words, 840 is 120% of $x$. We can write this in an equation as
$$ 1.2x = 840 . $$
So what is $x$? Divide both sides by 1.2:
$$ x = 840 \div1.2 = 700 , $$
so last year there were around 700 accidents. Use your calculator to find 120% of 700, and verify that it equals 840.